# friend suggestion in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I want to suggest some friends randomly to users, no matter if there is any mutual friends between suggestion and current session_user.

Here is what i have tried :

```
$sess = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['user_id']));

$qet = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user.id AS id, user.name AS name, user.u_name AS u_name, user.profile_pic AS profile_pic

FROM user INNER JOIN user_friend ON (user.id = user_friend.add_by_id) OR (user.id = user_friend.add_to_id) 

WHERE (user_friend.add_to_id != '$sess' or user_friend.add_by_id != '$sess') AND (user.id != '$sess') 

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

My table structure :

user_friend

> 1. id
> 2. add_by_id
> 3. add_to_id
> 4. added_on
> 5. accepted

user

> 1. id
> 2. name
> 3. u_name
> 4. profile_pic
> 5. email
> 6. password
> 7. gender

I am not getting the proper results, it suggests me those friends also who are already friend with me(current session_user).

Comment: `where (user_friend.add_to_id != '$sess' or user_friend.add_by_id != '$sess')` looks wrong, I guess it could be `and` (depends on whatever the table describes exactly). And you might want to add a `distinct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be "get a random user that's not a friend of the current user yet." If so, this would be a more direct sql translation:

```
SELECT user.id AS id, user.name AS name, user.u_name AS u_name, user.profile_pic AS profile_pic
FROM user
WHERE user.id <> '$sess' AND user.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT add_by_id FROM user_friend WHERE add_to_id = '$sess'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT add_to_id FROM user_friend WHERE add_by_id = '$sess'
)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

(NOTE: Not tested.)

Your original sql has a join that limits results to users that already have a connection to the current user, so that can never give you what you want. (If I understood your need correctly.)